# JQuery POST in javsascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to post some data in JSON in a server, but I am having problem . I have done with this way which is working:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Create Sensor</h2>

    <form id="form">
        <form enctype='application/json'>
            <input name='version' value='1.0.1'>
            <input name='sensors_sensor' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_name' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_type' value=''>
            <br>
            <input id="input" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Sensor" />
        </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#input').click(function() {
                    var fromData = {
                        "version": $('input[name=version]').val(),
                        "sensors": [{
                            "sensor": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                            "output": [{
                                "name": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                                "type": $('input[name=sensors_type]').val()
                            }]
                        }],

                    };

                    var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                    alert(fromDatan);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "abc.com",
                        headers: {
                            "x-api-key": "abcd=",
                            "content-type": "application/json"
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        data: fromDatan,

                        success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But I am trying to do this in another way but it is not happening. Please help me out.

This is the code not working:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Create Sensor</h2>

    <form id="form">
        <form enctype='application/json'>
            <input name='version' value='1.0.1'>
            <input name='sensors_sensor' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_name' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_type' value=''>
            <br>

            <button onclick="postSOS();">Create</button>
        </form>
        <script>

        function postSOS() {
          postSEN();
        }



        function postSEN() {

               // $('#input').click(function() {
                    var fromData = {
                        "version": $('input[name=version]').val(),
                        "sensors": [{
                            "sensor": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                            "output": [{
                                "name": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                                "type": $('input[name=sensors_type]').val()
                            }]
                        }],

                    };

                    var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                    alert(fromDatan);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "abc.com",
                        headers: {
                            "x-api-key": "abcd=",
                            "content-type": "application/json"
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        data: fromDatan,

                        success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                //});
        }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Error mess? What goes wrong?

Comment: @JoakimM JSON forming is correct but response state 0 and it is throwing error while compile in compileonline.com whereas the first code working correctly. I want to make this as a generic javascript function so that I can use it in different purpose.

Comment: ANyone please Help me out

Comment: Wrap your script in the head

Comment: @JoakimM can you please show how to do, I don't know much :(

Answer (score 0):

By placing your script in the head I got it working on this FIDDLE

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script>

        function postSOS() {
          postSEN();
        }



        function postSEN() {

               // $('#input').click(function() {
                    var fromData = {
                        "version": $('input[name=version]').val(),
                        "sensors": [{
                            "sensor": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                            "output": [{
                                "name": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                                "type": $('input[name=sensors_type]').val()
                            }]
                        }],

                    };

                    var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                    alert(fromDatan);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "abc.com",
                        headers: {
                            "x-api-key": "abcd=",
                            "content-type": "application/json"
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        data: fromDatan,

                        success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                //});
        }
        </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Create Sensor</h2>

    <form id="form">
        <form enctype='application/json'>
            <input name='version' value='1.0.1'>
            <input name='sensors_sensor' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_name' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_type' value=''>
            <br>

            <button onclick="postSOS();">Create</button>
        </form>

</body>

</html>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pxtk2xz5/)

Comment: Let me try, will let you know :)

Comment: Well, what do you expect to get from abc.com?

Comment: I am expecting this:
[{"entity":"wedwed","message":"Sensor already registered.","httpStatus":409}]

OR



[{"entity":"wedwedsd","message":"CREATED","httpStatus":201}]

Comment: Is you API-key valid?

Comment: this is just arbitary API and arbitary website as I can not give original API key and server due to security policy. But I am assuring you in my original code API key and url everything is valid and that is why my first code is working byt I am trying to this in different way.

Comment: @Jokaim this is just arbitary API and arbitary website as I can not give original API key and server due to security policy. But I am assuring you in my original code API key and url everything is valid and that is why my first code is working byt I am trying to this in different way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try if this works (just add your API key and URL): http://jsfiddle.net/gqLgf4vx/

```
var sensorForm = $("#form");
sensorForm.on("submit", postSen());

function postSen() {
    var formData = {
        "version": $('input[name=version]').val(),
            "sensors": [{
            "sensor": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                "output": [{
                "name": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                    "type": $('input[name=sensors_type]').val()
            }]
        }],

    },
        formDataStr = JSON.stringify(formData);

    sendAjax(formDataStr);
}

function sendAjax(formDataStr) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "abc.com",
        headers: {
            "x-api-key": "abcd=",
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: formDataStr,

        success: function (fromData, status, jqXHR) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: It is sending data even before clicking submit button

Comment: var sensorForm = $("#form");
      sensorForm.on("submit", postSen());

Can you please replace this thing?

The button should trigger function postSen() so that it takes data from form ant then POST. is that possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think  your first code  has extra form tag. 
So I updated your code.

```
   <form id="form">
        <form enctype='application/json'>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Jinthakur/0ne485u9/2/